# fs writeFile create temp file in app root

Tags: node.js, express, connect

I have the following code snippet to up[load files to server. Its working as expected in local environment but not in web server.

Using [connect-multiparty](https://www.npmjs.org/package/connect-multiparty)

```
path = req.files.FIELDNAME.path;
ogname = req.files.video.originalFilename;

function(path , ogname, callback) {
var fs = require('fs');
var uploadDir = process.cwd() + "/public/uploads/";
fs.readFile(path, function (err, data) {
  var originalFilename = new Date().getTime() + '-' + ogname.replace(/[\s,:-]+/g, "-");
  var newPath = uploadDir + originalFilename;
  var relatPath = "/uploads/" + originalFilename;
  fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function (err,result) {
    callback(relatPath);
  });
});
}
```

It creates files in `/public/uploads` as expected but leaves something in app root too. Like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/andrewrk/connect-multiparty

> This middleware will create temp files on your server and never clean
>   them up.

You have to delete them manually:

```
//....
fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function (err,result) {
    callback(relatPath);
    fs.unlink(path, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
});
```

Note that `process.cwd()` does *not* return the app root path, but the working directory. Use [`__dirname`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname) instead.

And using [rename](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_rename_oldpath_newpath_callback) is much faster and saves you from having to delete the file manually.

Comment: Will try and let you know. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

while the accepted answer works just fine, you can use [temp package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/temp)

which supports automatic removal